# Declare @NamedNativeQuery and @SqlResultSetMapping outside @Entity class

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In my maven project, I have 2 module:

`com.example.common` and

`com.example.myfeature`

In `common` module I have a package name `entities` that contains `@Entity` class

In `myfeature` module I have a package name `vos` that contain `DTO` or `Value Object` class.

```
com.example.common
+-----------------entities
+-------------------------Doctor.java
```

```
com.example.myfeature
+-----------------vos
+--------------------DoctorDTO.java
+-----------------repository
+--------------------DoctorRepository.java
```

I declared a `@SqlResultSetMapping` like this:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "resultMappingQuery",
        classes = @ConstructorResult(
                targetClass = DoctorDTO.class,
                columns = {
                        @ColumnResult(name = "doctorId", type = Long.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "gender", type = Gender.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "dateOfBirth", type = Date.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "description", type = String.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "avatarImg", type = String.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "title", type = String.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "addressTitle", type = String.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "address", type = String.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "department", type = String.class),
                })
)
```

If I declare `@SqlResultSetMapping` in common module, I have to import `DoctorDTO` from `myfeature` to `common`.

The problem is that I can't import `myfeature` module to `common` module, I will make tight coupling problem.

I'd like to declare `@SqlResultSetMapping` somewhere in `myfeature` module.

How can I do that?

Comment: `@SqlResultSetMapping` annotation should not be put on a POJO. Your entity manager can not discover your mapping when you annotate a SqlResultSetMapping in a non-entity.

You should lookback the way you split modules. Entity, Repository are the basic components of Persistence layer.

Comment: How about DTO? I think it should be contained in `feature` modules